# Push Notification problems?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode

I'm trying to make my app work with push notification and have followed this tutorial and it almost works like a charm... I get a problem though when trying to run the app and I think its a xcode3 to Xcode4 issue...

I get this error:
**2012-03-02 15:00:55.786 PushChat1[5276:707] Applications are expected to have a root view controller at the end of application launch**

And below is what I have in my **application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions**

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    //self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    _window.rootViewController = _viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    // Let the device know we want to receive push notifications
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] registerForRemoteNotificationTypes:
     (UIRemoteNotificationTypeBadge | UIRemoteNotificationTypeSound | UIRemoteNotificationTypeAlert)];

    return YES;
}
```

I'm really hoping for help and thanks in advance :-)

Answer (score 1):

this is not about push notfications. your problem is your viewcontroller. it seems to be nil. check your nib file, if all connections are correctly setup.

Comment: It seems to be nil??? Not sutra what you mean? And the nib file... Is that the same as xib?

Answer (score 1):

The error is not a notification error. You need a **rootViewController** to set to your app.

What's your `_viewController`?

Answer (score 1):

The error indicates the rootViewController property of your window is not set. So at assignment `_viewController` is nil (you're setting the property to nil) or `_window` is nil (you're sending a message to nil).

You're accessing your properties `_viewController` and `_window` directly. I don't see any code that's creating them. Make sure the objects exist before you use them. Check your xib to see if the correct outlets are set. If the objects are created in the property accessors make sure you access the properties using the dot notation (`self.window` / `self.viewController`) instead of accessing them directly.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not sure I understand, but here is some more... In my AppDelegate.h I have declared them I think:

class ViewController;

interface AppDelegate : UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>

property (strong, nonatomic) UIWindow *window;

property (strong, nonatomic) ViewController *viewController;

end

Comment: you have to check your nib file. is there a viewcontroller created?

Comment: put CFShow(_window); and CFShow(_viewController); on top of your method and show us, what gets logged to the console.